# Mute a specific notification

Tags: android, notification-listener

I am using a Notification Listener Service to receive any posted notification.
For some reason I would like to mute a notification that comes with a specific text. For example, if a Whatsapp notification is posted from a specific contact I may decide to mute that notification or to let it play as normal.
Is there any way to mute it?

I receive many emails from Office and all of them are important and I have to wake up in the night. But sometimes one is not important (the subject in the email is "not urgent") and I don't need to wake up in that case.

I know I can dismiss a notification but I want to let it display. I just want to mute the sound. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but another option might be to mute all Notifications, and instead have your Service sound a ringtone when the Notification doesn't contain "not urgent".

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think you can "mute" notification from other apps. Every App works in it's own sandbox so you can't react with an "multi-maintenance-tool" to the apps.

A better Idea is to use an extended e-mail client (like [K-9 Email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9)) and check, if there are features like yours in there. Or check other e-mail clients.